# CDN Versioning at File Level

Tags: svn, deployment, version, versioning, cdn

I was looking at Amazon.com and I noticed that their static files are versioned at the file level (example:  s9-multipack-min.*V171170235*.js ) instead of the directory level.

Can you please provide some good practices on how to manage different versions at the file level and where is the best place to store what is the latest version for each file?  We use SVN and our static files will be hosted on Amazon S3 CDN

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store multiple files at all. Just set up your rewrite module so it rewrites every `/js/filename.vNNN.js` to `/js/filename.js`.

As you can see the url

```
http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/us-site-wide-1.2.6/site-wide-11734552808.js._V169197_.js
```

points to actually the same content as

```
http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/browser-scripts/us-site-wide-1.2.6/site-wide-11734552808.js._V169174097_.js
```

does. Note on the last changed part

Comment: I am sorry that I did not make that clear, but my static files are hosted on Amazon S3 CDN, so I do not think that mod rewrite would work. Right?

Comment: @zerkms - sorry about that - any other thoughts?

Comment: @user627474: i think that in such case you can try to start to use some deployment software. And one of the deployment stages will be: give a proper name to js, upload it to amazon, specify the names in some config files (so you can build urls to that files in your application).

Comment: @zerkms - any good suggestions for open source deployment software?